# How do ZK-STARKs, ZK-SNARKs, and Bulletproofs compare in size and speed for range proofs?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

How do ZK-STARKs, ZK-SNARKs and Bulletproofs compare in size and speed for range proofs? The general behavior is depicted in [this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhpzO.jpg). But do those numbers scale linearly to the proof and verification times listed on [dalek-cryptography's bulletproofs page](https://github.com/dalek-cryptography/bulletproofs#comparative-performance), that has a 64-bit range proof taking 7.3ms and verification taking 1ms?  That is, would generating and verifying a ZK-STARK of a 64-bit range proof take microseconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paper in [this address](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/317) provides some more precise evaluations of various ZK proof techniques, including zk-STARKs, zk-SNARKs and Bullet proofs.

The have evaluation for a proof of membership for a Merkle tree with different number of leaves.