# How do I instantiate ZK-STARKs using Polynomial Commitments?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

In my exploration of zero-knowledge proofs, I have encountered various perspectives on the operational disparities among zk-SNARKs, zk-STARKs, and Bulletproofs, as documented in different blogs and discussions (such as the ones referenced in the provided links).

[How do ZK-STARKs, ZK-SNARKs, and Bulletproofs compare in size and speed for range proofs?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64610/how-do-zk-starks-zk-snarks-and-bulletproofs-compare-in-size-and-speed-for-rang)

[Why it is said that “zk-SNARKs need a trusted setup” to work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/89449/why-it-is-said-that-zk-snarks-need-a-trusted-setup-to-work)

[zk-SNARKs vs. Zk-STARKs vs. Bulletproofs: definitions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/74382/zk-snarks-vs-zk-starks-vs-bulletproofs-definitions)

The provided links offer valuable insights into the differences in size, speed, and reliance on trusted setups for these cryptographic protocols. However, a notable gap remains in the availability of systematically written algorithms for zk-STARKs and Bulletproofs, comparable to the clarity found in the Petkus paper for zk-SNARKs. While the Petkus paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.07221) offers a comprehensible explanation of zk-SNARKs using polynomial commitments and elucidates the proving and verification phases, I have encountered challenges in finding similarly well-documented constructions and instantiations for zk-STARKs and Bulletproofs. I found the paper on zk-STARKs [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2018/046.pdf) by Eli Ben-Sasson but it is so complex to understand the zk-STARKs.

I seek a detailed explanation, complete with mathematical formulations, of the proving and verification phases in zk-STARKs and Bulletproofs.

Thank you.